# Return partial sums of the array items as an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to solve [this](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5ce399e0047a45001c853c2b/train/javascript) kata on Codewars using JavaScript.

(sorry that I haven't copied and pasted the exercise here, the explanation is quite long)

I have some code that works for smaller arrays, but it is returning a server timeout error when I try to submit the solution:

```
function partsSums(ls) {
  const results = [];
  ls.forEach((c, i) => {results.push((ls.slice([i])).reduce((a, b) => {return(a+b)}))});
  results.push(0);
  return results;
};
```

I don't know how to make this code any more efficient so that I can submit the solution. Any help on this would be appreciated!

Comment: You must copy paste

Answer (score 1):

You could get a copy from the data and iterate from the end for assigning the sum.

```js
function partsSums(array) {
    var i = array.length,
        result = array.slice();
        
    result[i] = 0;
    while (i--) result[i] += result[i + 1];
    return result;
}

console.log(partsSums([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]));
//[21, 20, 18, 15, 11, 6, 0]

console.log(partsSums([744125, 935, 407, 454, 430, 90, 144, 6710213, 889, 810, 2579358]));
// [10037855, 9293730, 9292795, 9292388, 9291934, 9291504, 9291414, 9291270, 2581057, 2580168, 2579358, 0]
```